# I get different graph on neo4j. How to get 1-1 graph

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have sample data and want to build graph by neo4j.

```
shop    memberID    age type    number
Gyms    1           13  B       0-01
Gyms    1           14  A       0-02
Gyms    1           14  A       0-03
Gyms    1           20  B       0-04
Gyms    2           16  B       0-01
Gyms    2           16  B       0-02
Gyms    2           38  A       0-03
Gyms    2           38  A       0-04
Gyms    3           15  A       0-01
```

I expect to get same this picture.
[image]

In fact, I build graph and get this picture.
[image]

Could you tell me how to deal with my expected graph?

Here is neo4j code to run graph

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS row
MERGE (shop:shop {shop: row.shop})
MERGE (memberID:memberID {memberID: toInteger(row.memberID)})
MERGE (age:page {age: toInteger(row.age)})
MERGE (type:type {type: row.type})
MERGE (number:number {number: row.number})

MERGE path1 = (memberID)<-[:is_member]-(shop)
MERGE path2 = (age)<-[:is_age]-(memberID)
MERGE path3 = (type)<-[:is_type]-(age)
MERGE path4 = (number)<-[:is_number]-(type)

RETURN path1, path2, path3, path4
```

Comment: You have not explained you use case, but you may need to reconsider your data model. Here are just some of the potential questions/issues. Is it necessary for every property to sit in its own node? Why can a member have multiple ages? Does a `type` really being to an `age` -- or should it belong to a member?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems you shouldn't merge each node separately as for example, you want to have more than a single node for age 15 in your graph. You can modify your query as follows to merge each subsequent node in relationship to each parent node.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS row
MERGE (shop:shop {shop: row.shop})
MERGE (shop)-[:is_member]->(memberID:memberID {memberID: toInteger(row.memberID)})
MERGE (memberID)-[:is_age]->(age:page {age: toInteger(row.age)})
MERGE (age)-[:is_type]->(type:type {type: row.type})
MERGE (type)-[:is_number]->(number:number {number: row.number})
RETURN *
```

Comment: I also have other question how to deal with NULL value 

if some row in number column is NULL, it shows "Can't merge node using null property value for number"